# create connection pool TypeOrm

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, typeorm

How to create a connection pool using TypeOrm? While exploring TypeOrm, I wanted to create pool of connections for working with MySql

Below is the code snippet :

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DbConnectionToken',
    useFactory: async () => await createConnection({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8889,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'typeorm_test',
      entities: [
        __dirname + '/../**/**.entity{.ts,.js}',
      ],
      autoSchemaSync: true,
      logging: 'all',
    }),
  },
];
```

Answer (score 29):

TypeORM by default uses a connection pool which defaults to 10 connections. If you want to have custom pooling limit (advisable), the same can be mentioned for `connectionLimit` under `extra` options which are passed to the underlying MySQL driver.

```
 [
    {
        "name": "default",
        "type": "mysql",
        "host": "mysql.db",
        "port": 3306,
        "username": "appUser",
        "password": "appRandomPassword",
        "database": "entity_schema",
        "entities": [
            "dist/models/entities/**/*.js"
        ],
        "logging": [
            "error"
        ],
        "extra": {
            "connectionLimit": 5
        }
    }
]
```

[TypeORM Docs](https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#common-data-source-options)

[MySQL Connection pooling options](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options) which can be passed under `extra`, if required.

Comment: so meaning that if I have 10 clients running a 'long' query, the next concurrent clients will be in a queue waiting for an available connection?

Comment: so queueLimit = 0 meaning unlimited queue, so the 11th concurrent client will be in a queue unless one of the previous 10 clients has done, and its connection to the db can be assigned to the 11th, is it correct? :) thanks

Comment: doc link is expired. in their current docs can't find anywhere about default connections

Comment: Adjusted the link.

Answer (score 5):

TypeORM always creates you a connection pool out of the box, you don't need to setup anything. It uses one connection from the pool per one request to repository/entity manager method, or per one transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with version `0.3.10` there is a unified property to handle the connection pool maximum size, by using `poolSize: number` in your connection configuration.

Your config should now be something like

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DbConnectionToken',
    useFactory: async () => await createConnection({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8889,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'typeorm_test',
      entities: [
        __dirname + '/../**/**.entity{.ts,.js}',
      ],
      autoSchemaSync: true,
      logging: 'all',
      poolSize: 10,
    }),
  },
];
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't show a valid option in PostgresConnectionOptions

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an `extra` arguments to underlying database. From the [official doc](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection-options.md#common-connection-options) it looks like in typeorm, only mssql and mongo that support connection pool.

Comment: This is true, however you can still set connection limits for other databases by passing the correct (undocumented) options. For example with Postgres, you can pass `extra: { max: 10 }` to set the pool size to 10.

See this for reference:
[PostgresDriver.ts](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/c88e75b27d8fbd47ba46476a212e86281828b853/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts#L1043) and
[pg-pool/index.js](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/9d2c977ce9b13f8f3b024759b1deaec165564a6a/packages/pg-pool/index.js#L84)

Comment: 1 year later, still not documented. Thanks you so much

Comment: doesn't work in  pg

Comment: when I set this poolSize, and bombard the database with requests, the active connection actually exceeds to 500, 600.... and so definitely think it doesn't work in pg