# How to Set typeorm connection pool size in Nestjs? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I saw this link [create connection pool TypeOrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843248/create-connection-pool-typeorm)

This article explained

```
"extra": {
  "connectionLimit": 5
}
```

But I thought that this is just max limit of connection instead of creating connection pool in advance

How can I create typeorm(mysql) connection pool in Nestjs?

Answer (score 3):

From the words of one of the authors:

> TypeORM creates a connection pool and uses connection for a single
>   operation (find, save, remove, etc.) - it takes the connection, uses
>   it and releases it. That's it. If all connections are busy it waits
>   until any of them is released and then use it.

If you want your pool to have a max size, then `extra.connectionLimit` is the way to go.