# TypeORM mysql Pool does not exist

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm, connection-pooling, nestjs-typeorm

I am using the mysql driver with typeORM and sometimes typeORM throws a `"Error: Pool does not exist."` expection which seems to occur just randomly, but when it occurs the entire application is broken. Still some connections seem to be working fine, but some connections are broken.

On the mysql driver page I have found the same issue I am facing:
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/628

It says that it has something to do with pool names or something. In TypeORM pooling is configured by `"extra.connectionLimit"` as it is specified here:
[create connection pool TypeOrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843248/create-connection-pool-typeorm)

There seems to be no way to configure any name of pools, so I am wondering what TypeORM does in order to setup the connection pool. Maybe there is something which is not done correctly? Any help in this issue would be much appreciated because it is a very annoying issue.

`ormconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  ...
  extra: {
    connectionLimit: 100,
  },
  ...
}
```

Some logs from the application:
[image]

Comment: Please include an example of your TypeORM `mysql data source options` object so we can understand what features you are trying to leverage. The issue you linked is not necessarily the same. That issue was 10 years ago (some changes to the pool cluster feature have happened since then) and that person was working directly with the `mysql` module. You are working with `TypeORM` and using their `mysql` option which adds a layer of complication. The `PoolCluster` option can be complicated even when working directly with the module so using it via TypeORM will be even moreso.

Comment: Well, the connection and pool seem to be working fine, just out of the blue something happens and this issue occurs. As for the pool options it is only the following line: `extra: {  connectionLimit: 100,  },` I have added it to the question